# Teams Usage Report : getTeamUserActivityUserDetail - API not giving the new Attributes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-reporting

In Microsoft admin center, we can see the new columns available for the **Microsoft Teams User Activity** as specified in the following

[image: Teams User Activity report as in Office 365 Admin center]

On trying to retrieve the data vis Microsoft Graph API, we are getting the old attributes in response:

Request : [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D180')?$format=application/json](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period=%27D180%27)?$format=application/json)

[image: Response of the Beta Graph API]

On following the redirect link and downloaded the Response CSV file, I could see new attributes in that file

[image: Downloaded XLS file from the response]

Is I am missing anything in the request ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried it at my end with Graph API call, but i failed to see the new attributes in it. I dont see any other options in it to get the newer attributes. Also in the documentation they don't talk it either - so it's "by design" or works "as expected".

Comment: Being said that if you want to new attributes, then i see the following options:. You may want to consider filing a [feature request](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) with Teams engineering or wait till it becomes GA/v1.0!!

Comment: Does it helped you moving forward?

Comment: As I could retrieve the new column values in CSV, Microsoft might have made a mistake to update the new Column values in response as JSON. I was expecting those new attributes in the response.